# config find command to exclude certain directory

Tags: bash

How to config to permanently exclude certain directory for `find` command.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command
I tried to add the following alias to bashrc

```
alias find='find -not \( -path ./.git -prune \)'
```

seems not working.

In ripgrep you can config it. https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#configuration-file
So How to once for all config make find exclude certain directory like git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write it as a `myfind` wrapper script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
predicate_found=false skip_one=false
for arg do
  if "$skip_one"; then
    skip_one=false
  elif ! "$predicate_found"; then
    case $arg in
      (-depth | -ignore_readdir_race | -noignore_readdir_race | \
       -mount | -xdev | -noleaf | -show-control-chars) ;;
      (-files0-from | -maxdepth | -mindepth) skip_one=true;;
      (['()!'] | -[[:lower:]]?*)
        predicate_found=true
        set -- "$@" ! '(' -name .git -prune ')' '('
    esac
  fi
  set -- "$@" "$arg"
  shift
done
if "$predicate_found"; then
  set -- "$@" ')'
else
  set -- "$@" ! '(' -name .git -prune ')'
fi
exec find "$@"
```

Which inserts `!` `(` `-name` `.git` `-prune` `)` before the first non-option predicate¹ (or at the end if no predicate is found), and wraps the rest between `(` and `)` to avoid problems with expressions using `-o`.

For instance, `myfind -L . /tmp /etc -maxdepth 1 -type d -o -print` would become `find -L . /tmp /etc -maxdepth 1 ! '(' -name .git -prune ')' '(' -type d -o -print ')'`.

That `prune`s *all* `.git` directories. To prune only the ones at depth 1 of each of the directories passed as arguments, with FreeBSD's `find`, you could add a `-depth 1` before `-name .git`.

`.git` dirs could end up being traversed if you add some `-mindepth 2` (or any number greater than 2).

Note that `-prune` cannot be used in combination with `-depth` (or `-delete` which implies `-depth`).

---

<sup>¹ here taking care of the GNU `find` *option predicates* to avoid its warnings if you insert things before them. It uses heuristics for that. It could be fooled if you used for instance BSD's `myfind -f -my-dir-starting-with-dash-...`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can't configure `find` to ignore a directory, that's just not how it works. you can, however, use a function (not an alias, because you need it to be able to take arguments) instead. Add this to your shell's initialization files where you were trying to add the alias:

```
my_find(){
  path="$1"
  shift
  find "$path" -not \( -path ./.git -prune \) "$@"
}
```

You can then run something like this:

```
my_find /target/path -name something
```

One significant drawback of this approach is that you will need to always give a target path and cannot default to searching in the current directory.

Comment: Another drawback is that you can’t specify multiple paths, and that expressions with `-o` won’t work as expected.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, you can't add more paths. But why would `-o` specifically not work? I just tried with `my_find . -name file -o -name new2.csv` and found both `file` and `new2.csv` just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking in general terms, but `-prune` means it doesn’t matter. (In general terms, `my_find ... -A -o -B` runs `find ... -not ... -A -o -B`, where one would want `find ... -not ... -A -o -not ... -B`.)

Comment: There is however another problem, which is that the path filtering only works for `my_find .`.